# Angularjs checkbox like gmail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Im newbie in angularjs. 
Now im having issues with a checkbox.
First: my web are paging , sorting and change page size by call api to get data from server in factory:

```
this.getData = function(page , sortColumm, sortType , pageSize, searchText){
$http({
        method = get;
        url = "api/data?page="+page +"&sortColumm=" +sortColumm +"&sortType="+sortType +"&pagesize="+pageSize+"&search="+searchText;
    }).success(function (data) {
    }).error(function (error) {
    });
}
```

now i have a page using angularjs to bind data using funciton getData.
html:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"></th>
        <th>Administrator Name</th>
        <th >Administrator Type</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="gladmin in gladmins" ng-switch on="gladmin.isEnabled"
        on-finish-render="resizetable">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="gladmin.Selected" value="{{gladmin.id}}" ng-click="selectionAdmin(gladmin.id)"></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="">{{gladmin.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{gladmin.type}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

controller

```
app.controller('adminPage',function(){
   // call getData
   $scope.checkAll=function(){
       // what should i write here?
       // i want check all is for current page, next page checkall = fall, 
       // same GMAIL
   }
   $scope.selectionAdmin = function(id){
       // what should i do here
   }
})
```

All i want is the checkall same the checkall in gmail ? anyone help me ? please, i am new bie in this!

i find some link here : http://plnkr.co/edit/N98IKTcHoZMCs18FjSRF?p=preview
http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

but it work not same i want !

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to understand the question but I think you just want a property of ng-checked="isAllChecked" in your ng-repeat for the inputs.  When that value is set to true all of them should check.

Comment: Also ng-change would be better then ng-click here that way you are always going on change of the input even if you didn't click it but was changed elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for feedback, all i want here what  i shoud do (with checkall and selectionAdmin function) same the checkall box in gmail !

Comment: Well they don't use check boxes they fake it with Divs and background images.  Basically they are just setting properties on divs that adjust a class and displays differently.  All the logic they are doing is based on like a ng-class logic if variable is true then display background image of check.

Comment: Basically the examples you have seen show using a directive or something to generate the markup and have access to the markup.  http://plnkr.co/edit/N98IKTcHoZMCs18FjSRF?p=preview is the example of that.  The second is for some weird model addon for checklist.  Frankly this is very clunky in angular to do because you didn't make it the angular way. Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked  add a ng-Checked expression to the ng-repeat and have it resolve to true and then set that variable to true in your other expression.

Comment: thanks your feedback !
now i have some other issue with select checkbox. When i tick checkall box in the first load page, all data will be selects. All item in currentpage is check, but when i uncheck one or some item in first page, then click next to jump second page, i want all item in second page selected. but it not ? i thinks because i dont know the data second page when the first load and click select all ? how can i fix that ?

Comment: If you are doing some sort of pagination then you have some sort of array of the current displayed items on the page, you will have to loop through them in your Check all function or handle that through the data call.  It look like you are getting all your data through promises and pagination is happening on the first page instead of all the data being set and doing local filtering.  Angular hasn't created those items yet till you click to paginate the page.  You would have to do have some sort of checkAllOnLoad toggle and check them all when it is loaded.

Comment: This is very risky because it won't keep track of the items you checked or unchecked from the first page.  I don't think this will eventually work the way you want because you have no way of keeping track of items that are paginated with this implementation.